# Windows updating hostname on network disconnect

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp

We have a problem with a desktop app system which reads hostname and uses it to set context for the execution.

One of the conditions is when it is connected to Network it reads the hostname, call it as [hostname] and uses it to set the context. But one of the users disconnected the machine from network which inadvertently set the hostname different, call it as [hostname1] (It really appended 1 to the hostname). When the user got back to the network the hostname was updated back to [hostname], the old name. This created some inconsistencies in our software.

Any idea why this can happen and is it an expected behavior from OS and Networking stack?
Any help will be appreciated

The system is running in Windows XP SP2. Are there any other factors which can affect this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It's expected. An administrator can change a system's host name as he pleases. The networking system can change a system's host name if it changes networks as it may have a different host name on each network.

It sounds like your software makes a false assumption. You need to decide whether you want to just grab the hostname once and accept that it may not be current or develop an organized way to consistently handle a hostname change.

If you think about it, it pretty much has to be this way. Otherwise, when would the hostname be determined?

Comment: I do understand that software is making false assumptions but I want to understand the behavior of the networking system in this. Thanks for the explanation.